# EF Core loads all navigation properties except one

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables

```
public class ConcreteParameter
{
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
    public Parameter Parameter { get; set; }

    public string AnotherId {get; set}

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

ParameterId from ConcreteParameter is foreign key to Parameter table.

{ParameterId, AnotherId} primary key

In Parameter table lets say I have {Id: 1, DefaultValue = "White"}

In Concrete table 3 lines

ParameterId   Value   AnotherId

1             Blue    100

1             Red     200

1             Green   300

If I want to include the Parameter navigation property

Entities.Include(p => p.Parameter),
One Entity will have Parameter null and the other 2 will have it loaded, I don't know why.
If I have 10 entities, 9 will load the Parameter navigation property but one will have it null.
If I have 1 record, the navigation property is loaded.
The problem is when the foreign key ParameterId is duplicated.

My configuration:

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ConcreteParameter > builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => new { p.AnotherId, p.ParameterId });
        builder.HasOne(g => g.Parameter).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Parameter>(g => g.ParameterId);
        builder.HasIndex(ug => new { ug.ParameterId }).IsUnique(false);
    }
```

Comment: You said doesn't load when `ParameterId ` is duplicated, seems like you need a One-Many relationship instead a One-One?

Comment: ConcreteParameter has only one Parameter.

But when there are 3 ConcreteParameters with the same foreign key (ParameterId), but different "AnotherId", all 3 should load the same Parameter as a navigation property. But one of them has the navigation property null.

Comment: `WithOne()` is the problem/cause of the issue.  Must be `.WithMany()` since you have repeating `ParameterId` values in `ConcreteParameter`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! That was the problem.
Because I didn't need a navigation property from Parameter to ConcreteParameter, I put "WithOne()" but now with "WithMany" that is fixed.

Strange that all values except one were loaded...